# A viscoelastic material with nonconvex memory kernel?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, stress-strain, physical-properties-of-materials

The title is basically my question. Viscoelastic materials are characterized by a constitutive equation between stress and strain involving a convolution integral. This integral is weighted with a relaxation kernel (or memory kernel).

Usually, the memory kernel is convex and decreasing (actually, it is often an exponential), but I was wondering if there exist materials for which the memory kernel is nonconvex.

Thank you very much to anyone willing to respond!

Comment: I know very little about this topic, but from searching around, this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=qZaM_gdp52AC&pg=PR14&lpg=PR14&dq=memory+kernel+viscoelastic+%22nonconvex%22&source=bl&ots=yoB8Z8LEUv&sig=ACfU3U2EjIMA_9uNVBs31R6Ugu-ODoKSyA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhv47l6JbsAhUSW60KHQOBBlwQ6AEwB3oECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=memory%20kernel%20viscoelastic%20%22nonconvex%22&f=false) has a section nonconvex kernels. Hopefully they give some sort of example.

Comment: Lorenzo, was the book helpful?

Comment: Hi! Sorry, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything worth it in the book. The only thing I've found is a sentence in this paper (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00397-005-0443-6) by Hanyga: "Complete monotonicity is not a universal feature of weakly dissipative viscoelastic systems. [... see formula (10) ...] Oscillatory relaxation appears in seawater with damped bubble oscillations. It can also be generated by including mass in spring-dashpot models."

However, I couldn't find much literature supporting the sentence.

Comment: That's very interesting question. Sorry I did not see your reply to my comment, because you didn't tag me with @NikeDattani. Only the person that asked the question gets notifications on comments, otherwise you need to tag the user you're talking to. Do you know of any materials with a non-monotonic memory kernel? A parabola can be convex but non-monotonic; have you ever seen such convex but non-monotonic memory kernel?

Comment: @NikeDattani, unfortunately I come from the mathematics field, so I don't know anything on materials. In particular, no, I don't know anything about viscoelastic materials with nonmonotonic kernel. However, I'm pretty sure the kernel HAS to be monotonic. Having a nonmonotonic kernel would mean that the material "weights" events happened in the long past more than events happened in recent past, which does not seem very physical.

Comment: @LorenzoLiverani I have replied to your comment in the [Physical Properties of Materials](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55867625#55867625) chat room.